# htaccess question mark not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, seo

first my english not good, i can do mistakes

I'm using htaccess for sefurl, i want to send some filter or pagination values with sefurl like this:

Adress: `http://sitename.com.tr/htaccess/yatak-ortuleri-modules-2-entryId-1?pageNum=2`

Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404/

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)?(.*) index.php?page=$2&menuId=$3&$4=$5$6 [L,NC]
```

Query String: 
`page=modules&menuId=2&entryId=1`

REQUEST_URI:
`/htaccess/yatak-ortuleri-modules-2-entryId-1?pageNum=2`

I want to values after question mark in query_sting or should i use request_uri ?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Change `[L,NC]` to `[L,QSA]` and remove `?(.*)` and this `$6` see if that works

Comment: Thank you so much Prix, that working for me. Have a nice a day.